# Give some depth to my input

Tags: css

I´m trying to do a basic effect in css to give some depth to my input, something like the image below. I´m trying to do with my code below but anything is missing here because my result is not icual to my image example.

My html:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
</form>
```

My css:

```
input[type="text"] {background-color:#232323; color:#fff; border:1px solid #151515;  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;}
```

What I´m trying:

[image]

Comment: by depth, do you mean the spacing between the borders and the text?

Comment: No, I´m talking about the effect on the image that I put that gives a idea that the input is inside de background, I dont know how to explain this better, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You will need at last 2 elements here: one for the dark-grey background, the other for the input.

The rest of my answer has been tested and works in IE10 +, FF & Chrome. If you're looking for IE support for 9 and below this wont work out of the box. It also relies on setting some fixed widths.

You'll recall I mentioned two elements, well you [should be using a label](http://www.webaxe.org/placeholder-attribute-is-not-a-label/) tag anyway.

Adjust your HTML to te following:

```
<label>Search
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
</label>
```

The follwoing CSS positions the input to hide `label` text.

```
label {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#111;
    position:relative;
    color:#FFF;
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
}
label input {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 2px #CCC;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 2px #CCC;
    box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 2px #CCC;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;
    border:none;
    padding:3px;
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
    padding:5px;
    width:200px;
    height:16px;
    top:7px; /* This is ((label hight + (padding * 2)) - this height)/2;*/
             /* e.g. ((20 +  (2 * 10)) - 16)/2 */
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jc4wF/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean, but is this getting close to what you want?

```
input[type="text"] {
   background-color:#232323;
   color:#fff;
   padding:2px 5px;
   border:5px solid #151515;
   -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is not that. I´m not explaining well, but Its like the input being inside of the background. To give the idea that the input is into and its for the user write data there.